ML Gradient Descent Convergence Theorem
Does there exist a generalization of this theorem, by Yurii Nesterov in Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization (2004) which relaxes the assumption that the loss function is convex and shows that gradient descent converges to a critical point in the parameter space?
Please see below for the theorem which is paraphrased to include assumptions and definitions from earlier in the text.
Corollary 2.1.2. If the learning rate $h=1/L$ and $f$ is a convex and differentiable $L$-Lipschitz function, then performing gradient descent for $k$ iterations yields a solution which satisfies $$f(x_k) - f^* \leq \dfrac{2L \lVert x_0 - x^* \rVert^2}{k+4}$$

Pretty sure $f$ is not $L$-Lipschitz, but $L$-smooth (i.e. its gradient is $L$-Lipschitz). Regarding your question, the answer is yes, see e.g. https://www.mit.edu/~gfarina/2024/67220s24_L07_gradient_descent/L07.pdf (Or other lecture notes; the keyword is "descent lemma").
